# Change font colour of a textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to open an Excel file, go to the first sheet in the file, and change the text colour of textbox1 to red.

The only way I have managed to do it so far is via recording the macro.

It gives me

```
Workbooks.Open (fPath & sName)

            Sheets(1).Select

  ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox1")).Select

  With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 262).Font.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
    End With
```

That's fine; however the length of the text is variable so I get an error with the code if it is less than the 262 characters above.

I tried to introduce

```
CharCount = Len(textbox1.Text)
```

However I get  error 424 Object required

I initially tried

```
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

but got error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the font colour of the entire textbox (i.e. not just certain characters) then skip the `Characters` method. Also you shouldn't rely on `.Select`, `ActiveSheet` and the likes. Set proper references instead.

This works:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Shape

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & sName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
Set s = ws.Shapes("TextBox 1")

s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
Sub Button2()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Textbox1")
    sh.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Excel 2000 (long story) and I conditionally set the color of text box "M_in_out" in "Sheet7" with the following.

```
Private Sub M_in_out_LostFocus()
Dim sh As Sheet7
Set sh = Sheet7

vx = CInt(M_in_out.Value)
If vx > 0 Then
  sh.M_in_out.ForeColor = vbBlack
Else
  sh.M_in_out.ForeColor = vbRed
End If

sh.Cells(23, 6).Value = sh.Cells(23, 6).Value + vx
End Sub
```

You should probably use more meaningful variable names etc!.